# How to Access PagesSection Property in Code-behind of Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, properties

I'm in the code behind of a user control. I need to access one of the page's properties (`EnableSessionState`).

Originally, this would be defined something like this in aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" %>
```

However, I want to dynamically change this value in the code behind.

I looked at this answer:

```
PagesSection pages = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("").GetSection("system.web/pages") as PagesSection;
pages.EnableSessionState = PagesEnableSessionState.ReadOnly;
```

Unfortunately, I'm just trying to read the header. Also considered this answer:

```
PagesSection pagesSection = new PagesSection();
pagesSection.EnableSessionState = PagesEnableSessionState.ReadOnly;
```

But I'm not trying to read default values, I'm trying to set the actual page's values.

Unfortunately, there is no property like `this.Page.PagesSection`, so is there another way of going about this?

Comment: This question is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45049194/alter-session-state-when-enablesessionstate-is-readonly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the goal was to modify session state behaviour, [according to this blog](https://itsmycornerswati.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/asp-net-concurrent-ajax-requests-and-session-state-blocking/), it is possible to access using the following line:

```
Context.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);
```